cubic-bezier CSS Animation with no keyframes
I'm trying to copy the animation shown in this video but I can't get it to work - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aCWeVAu0v2U
I feel like I've tried everything to make it work but nothing I do works.
My code:
<img class="item" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2024/07/03/08/05/hot-air-balloon-8869138_1280.jpg" alt="">
<img class="item" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2024/07/03/08/05/hot-air-balloon-8869138_1280.jpg" alt="">
<img class="item" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2024/07/03/08/05/hot-air-balloon-8869138_1280.jpg" alt="">
<img class="item" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2024/07/03/08/05/hot-air-balloon-8869138_1280.jpg" alt="">
<img class="item" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2024/07/03/08/05/hot-air-balloon-8869138_1280.jpg" alt="">

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.item {
  width: 300px;
}

.item:hover {
  transition: width 0.5s cubic-bezier(.87,-1.38,.03,1.54);
}


Please have a look into this How to ask and minimal reproducible code.

The transition property should be inside the .item selector, and you should specify the width that it should transition to in the .item:hover selector.

A transition does not use keyframes, animation does.

you can put the transition in the initial state of your .item like that :
    .item {
      width: 300px;
      transition: width 0.5s cubic-bezier(.87,-1.38,.03,1.54);
    }
    
    .item:hover {
      width: 500px;
    }

if the transition is in the :hover, it will only apply when the element is hovered over, so there will be no transition animation
took the 500px from the video btw
